# C# System.NullReferenceException NSoup

Tags: c#, jsoup, html-parsing

```
for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
{
    NSoupClient.Connect("https://steamcommunity.com/gid/" + x)
               .UserAgent("Firefox")
               .Timeout(10000)
               .Get();
}
```

This piece of code will throw me this error (and it always stops when the int is 5):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in NSoup.dll

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I've seen this before, but what is null??

Comment: Seems You are not the only having the issue - https://nsoup.codeplex.com/workitem/8 Seems as an issue with library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using a `WebClient` to download the page.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    string html = wc.DownloadString(url);
    Document document = NSoupClient.Parse(html);
}
```